# Create a table from REST object by setting data in columnar manner

Tags: html, angularjs, user-interface

I have a REST service, which returns this object:

```
[
  {
    "id": 100,
    "value": "2452"
  },
  {
    "id": 100,
    "value": "2458"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "2457"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "2459"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "value": "2460"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "value": "3458"
  }
]
```

Now, using this GET service, I want the following table to be built in angular and show it in UI.

```
100    1    4    5
-------------------
2452 2457 2460 3458
2458 2459
```

i.e. the unique ids should create the header and the list of values associates to each header value will be appended to respective column.

I have tried something with ng-repeat like this:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th ng-repeat="column in cols">{{column.id}}</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td ng-repeat="column in cols">
    <md-list>
      <md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="val in column.values">
        <md-checkbox ng-model="item.done"></md-checkbox>
        <div class="md-list-item-text">
          ??
        </div>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>

  </td>
</tr>
```

But still wondering how to do the same? Please help.

Comment: Do you use filters on your data to display only informations that you need in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use `groupBy` filter.

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', ['angular.filter']);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
  {
    "id": 100,
    "value": "2452"
  },
  {
    "id": 100,
    "value": "2458"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "2457"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "2459"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "value": "2460"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "value": "3458"
  }
];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="aCtrl">
  <table border="1">
<tr>
    <th ng-repeat="col in data | groupBy: 'id'">{{col[0].id}}</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td ng-repeat="col in data | groupBy: 'id'">
   <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="c in col">
       <td> {{c.value}}</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```